# Hello world flask program turns off then off

Tags: python, flask

So, I wanted to get into flask, I installed it with:

```
pip3 install flask
```

I did not get any errors, Im following a tutorial, when I go to my command line ( im on linux ) I go to the directory and do:

```
python3.6

import index.py
```

The program turns on then almost immediaitly off. 
Code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def result():
    return "hi"


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start your server using `__name__ == "__main__"`, you can do it by `python index.py`.